# Only show files with certain amount of folders using regex

Tags: regex

I have a load of file address' in excel:

```
\\server_name\Folder_level1\Folder_level2\Folder_level3\Folder_level\
\\server_name\Folder_level1\Folder_level2\
\\server_name\Folder_level1\Folder_level2\Folder_level3\
```

I only want the bottom two address' to show up.

So using regex I have tried to do this:

```
/(?:\).{5,6}
```

only allowing 5 or 6 back slashes but this doesn't work any ideas?

Comment: Please take your time and give us some clear examples.

Comment: You just changed the folder names form xxxxxx to something else. What I meant is: input -> output examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?:[^\\]*\\){5,6}$
```

Comment: This would match xxxxxxx\xxx\xxxxxxxXXxx\xxxxxxx\XXxxxXXxxxxXxxxx\ as well (missing \\ at the beginning). I know that was not the question, but could cause problems if the path list contains stuff like that.

Comment: @wumpz: Right, but it is not required in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp will show the last 1 or 2 path components:

```
([^\\]*\\){1,2}$
```

Comment: I did not ask for this?

Comment: @user2768038: So what does it mean: "I only want the bottom two to show up."?

Comment: @user2768038: Oh, it looks like you wanted ([^\\\]*\\\){5,6} ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your pathes start with **\\**

```
\\\\([^\\]+\\){3,4}$
```

So this allows after **\\** 3 or 4 times a **xxxx\**, matching the last two path examples of you and not the first one.